# How to handle java passwd reading when System.console() returns null?

Tags: java, unix, console-application

I'm writing a commandline program that prompts for a passwd and I don't want it to do local echo of the password characters.  After some searches, I have stumbled upon `System.console().readPassword()`, which seems great, *except* when dealing with pipes in Unix.  So, my example program (below) works fine when I invoke it as:

```
% java PasswdPrompt
```

but fails with Console == null when I invoke it as

```
% java PasswdPrompt | less
```

or

```
% java PasswdPrompt < inputfile
```

IMHO, this seems like a JVM issue, but I can't be the only one who has run into this problem so I have to imagine there are some easy solutions.

Any one?

Thanks in advance

```
import java.io.Console;

public class PasswdPrompt {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Console cons = System.console();
        if (cons == null) {
            System.err.println("Got null from System.console()!; exiting...");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        char passwd[] = cons.readPassword("Password: ");
        if (passwd == null) {
            System.err.println("Got null from Console.readPassword()!; exiting...");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        System.err.println("Successfully got passwd.");
    }
}
```

Comment: just tested under Ubuntu 10.10 and the same error happens, so you're not the only one.

Answer (score 0):

From the Java [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/cl.html) page :

> If System.console returns NULL, then
>   Console operations are not permitted,
>   either because the OS doesn't support
>   them or because the program was
>   launched in a noninteractive
>   environment.

The problem is most likely because using a pipe falls out of "interactive" mode and using an input file uses that as `System.in`, thus no `Console`.

** **UPDATE** **

Here's a quick fix. Add these lines at then end of your `main` method :

```
if (args.length > 0) {
   PrintStream out = null;
   try {
      out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(args[0]));
      out.print(passwd);
      out.flush();
   } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   } finally {
      if (out != null) out.close();
   }
}
```

And invoke your application like

```
$ java PasswdPrompt .out.tmp; less .out.tmp; rm .out.tmp
```

However, your prompted password will reside in plaintext (though hidden) file until the command terminates.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  The thing is this is silly -- the underlying shell still has a tty allocated and can still make all of the relevant system calls, so I can't understand what the JVM has done to break this.

Comment: The JVM hasn't actually broken anything.  The problem is that it is not using "/dev/tty" to get the console.  (Or maybe it is ... and the name of the device file is different on your platform.)

Comment: I appreciate the help, but your work around is just not something I can viably ask my users to do every time they run my tool.  I may be wrong, but I can't imagine I'm the only one who has ever had this problem, so there must be some sort of reasonable solution.  In any case, your solution doesn't handle the 2nd use case 'java PasswdPrompt < input'.  Yes, I could add another similar hack, but in the end, I just want this cmdline tool to operate the way that all the other cmdline unix tools work.  Thanks again.

Comment: just create a shell script to run your program.

Answer (score 0):

So, for some reason, when System.console() returns null, terminal echo is always off, so my problem becomes trivial.  The following code works exactly as I wanted.  Thanks for all the help.

```
import java.io.*;


public class PasswdPrompt {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
        Console cons = System.console();
        char passwd[];
        if (cons == null) {
            // default to stderr; does NOT echo characters... not sure why
            System.err.print("Password: ");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                            System.in));
            passwd= reader.readLine().toCharArray();
        }
        else {
            passwd = cons.readPassword("Password: ");
        }
        System.err.println("Successfully got passwd.: " + String.valueOf(passwd));
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that your solution is ideal.  Basically, it means that the password has to be in the file or pipe that your application is reading from.  A lot of people would consider that to be insecure.