# Redirect input to a Java application inside a bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I am using the ftm cli by Oracle. When I run a command, it asks for a password by saying "Enter a password". I am writing a script which uses this command and so I want to enter the password programatically.
Here's what I have tried -

```
echo "password" | java -jar ftmcli.jar list
```

But this doesn't work. Any idea what to do to make it work?

Comment: Where's the call to the ftm cli?

Comment: Maybe you need to use `expect` in alternative

Comment: @MarkSetchell I have replaced the call to ftm cli by java command. The actual call looks like `java -jar ftmcli.jar list`

Comment: I think your only hope is `expect` as suggested by @CWLiu - have a look here for an example http://www.admin-magazine.com/Articles/Automating-with-Expect-Scripts

Comment: @MarkSetchell Does expect  work for java jar command?

Comment: @AnikaKelhanka It should do - post a question and tag it with `expect` - it’s free

Answer (score 4):

Without being able to look into the source code of `ftmcli`, I presume that Oracle is using `Console.readPassword()` from the `java.io.Console` class. However, there is a snag with this function:

> **public final class Console**
>
> Methods to access the character-based console device, if any,
>   associated with the current Java virtual machine.
>
> Whether a virtual machine has a console is dependent upon the
>   underlying platform and also upon the manner in which the virtual
>   machine is invoked. If the virtual machine is started from an
>   interactive command line without redirecting the standard input and
>   output streams then its console will exist and will typically be
>   connected to the keyboard and display from which the virtual machine
>   was launched. If the virtual machine is started automatically, for
>   example by a background job scheduler, then it will typically not have
>   a console.
>
> If this virtual machine has a console then it is represented by a
>   unique instance of this class which can be obtained by invoking the
>   System.console() method. If no console device is available then an
>   invocation of that method will return null.

By piping/redirecting the `stdout` of `echo` to the JVM, the Java method `System.console()` will return `null` and hence not read anything from your redirection.

Look at the following questions which handle the same problem, but on Java side: ["How to handle java passwd reading when System.console() returns null?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326406/how-to-handle-java-passwd-reading-when-system-console-returns-null?rq=1) or [How to pipe input to Java program with bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724646/how-to-pipe-input-to-java-program-with-bash)

On your side, there is more or less nothing you can really do. Executing `echo $password | java -jar ftmcli.jar list` or `java -jar ftmcli.jar list <<< $password` will always fail as long Oracle doesn't change the way how `ftmcli` reads the password from `stdin`.

Comment: One thing you could try is to send the password to `/proc/$(pgrep -f '-jar ftmcli.jar list)/fd/0` (`stdin` of the particular process) after you launched `ftmcli` which is then waiting for input. However, I didn't try this and can't guarantee it will work.

Comment: Nice answer. Sometimes passwords can be passed by setting environment variables (e.g. `export FTM_PASSWORD=secret`). No idea if that is possible here.

Answer (score 1):

If you are ready for a one time password setup, then follow the below steps.

1. run java -jar ftmcli.jar   --save-auth-key
2. You will be prompted for teh password and once it is given, the file will be uploaded and a ftmclikeystore file is created under ftmcli folder.
3. Now as long as if you don't change the user, then ftmcli will take the password from this file.

Answer (score 0):

Found this little but fantastic tool called `expect` does the magic:

```
$ ./expect.script
spawn java -cp /tmp/brm-test/oraclepki.jar:/tmp/brm-test/BRMActions.jar com.oracle.installer.brm.BRMInstallHelper 7 /tmp/brm-test/client upgC
Enter Password for the wallet:
$
```

Perhaps it's not very much visible in the snippet above, but it is working:

```
$ cat /tmp/brm-test/client/.wp
upgC=MyMag1cPa$$word#
```

What is in the `expect.script`?

```
$ cat expect.script
#!/usr/bin/expect

stty -echo

spawn java -cp /tmp/brm-test/oraclepki.jar:/tmp/brm-test/BRMActions.jar com.oracle.installer.brm.BRMInstallHelper 7 /tmp/brm-test/client upgC

expect "Enter Password for the wallet:"
send "MyMag1cPa$$word#\r"

interact
```

Seems this can be used also in Chef, [see this cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/expect).

I hope it will help,
Jarek