Calling a Java program with System.console().readPassword() call from a shell script
We have a third-party Java application that uses System.console().readPassword() method. It cannot be modified. We need to call it from a non-interactive shell script that should pass password to that application. Piping password to the application does not appear to work. Is there a way to do this?
Test program:
import java.io.Console;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Console console = System.console();
        if (console == null) {
            System.err.println("Cannot acquire console");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        char[] passwordArray = console.readPassword("Enter password: ");
        System.out.println("Password: " + String.valueOf(passwordArray));
    }
}

Test shell script that does not work:
#!/bin/sh
export TEST_PASSWORD="test password"
echo "Test Password: $TEST_PASSWORD"
echo $TEST_PASSWORD | java Main


"Does not work" means that console equals null? Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326406/how-to-handle-java-passwd-reading-when-system-console-returns-null

use tools like expect or script

@elmiomar how? script "echo xx | java Main" still results in "Cannot acquire console". Voting to reopen so that someone can add a specific answer (the dupe is not directly relevant).

@k314159 If script doesn't work, try expect. You can find examples here: https://phoenixnap.com/kb/linux-expect. First, spawn your Java app, expect the "Enter password:" prompt, then send your password.

Thank you, @elmiomar. expect seems to do what I need.
